# need your help Mysql ERROR I tried but failed:

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to run a app cloned from following repo
https://github.com/myogeshchavan97/fullstack_banking_app and stuck with mysql

**I get following error when i run source /server/scripts.sql
I am using latest Server version: 8.0.23 Homebrew**

1. ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
   syntax to use near 'bank_account' at line 1
2. ERROR 1064 (42000): You
   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
   to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
   'BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,   first_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
   last_name V' at line 2
3. ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your
   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
   version for the right syntax to use near 'BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT
   NULL,   access_token VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,   userid B' at line 2

**scripts**

```
CREATE DATABASE bank_account;

CREATE TABLE bank_user(
  userid BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  unique(email)
);

CREATE TABLE TOKENS(
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  access_token VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  userid BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(userid) REFERENCES bank_user(userid)
);
```

I get this error I tried with backticks as but unfortunately didn't work...I would appreciate your insight.

Comment: `BIGSERIAL` is a PostGreSQL datatype, but you've tagged this with [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server]. These are three different products. Which are you using?

Comment: I have removed the conflicting tags. Please [edit] your qusetion and tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE bank_user( userid BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, first_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, unique(email) );

CREATE TABLE TOKENS( id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, access_token VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL, userid BIGINT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(userid) REFERENCES bank_user(userid) );
```

check the following [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-postgresql-typemapping.html) for mappings between PostgreSQL and MySQL.

In your case, instead of `BIGSERIAL` you need to use `BIGINT.`

Comment: In addition, replace PostgreSQL '\c' with MySQL 'USE' to select the bank_account database: USE bank_account;

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in MySQL would be:

```
CREATE TABLE bank_user (
  userid BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  unique(email)
);

CREATE TABLE TOKENS (
  id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  access_token VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  userid BIGINT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES bank_user(userid)
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a56ca22ce20d9c1f1015a13213a4d841) is a db<>fiddle.

The equivalent of `SERIAL` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Some comments:

- 32 characters may or may not be big enough for names.  It is certainly not big enough for emails, which can get pretty long.
- The password should be encrypted.  Do not store clear-text passwords in the data.
- I would be surprised if you really needed `BIGINT` for the `userid`.  Are you really planning on having *billions* of users?  A 4-byte integer should be sufficient.
- `NOT NULL` is redundant when you declare a column to be the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @Gordon for this equivalent code for mysql.
It worked for me!!

The equivalent in MySQL would be:

```
CREATE TABLE bank_user (
  userid BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  unique(email)
);

CREATE TABLE TOKENS (
  id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  access_token VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  userid BIGINT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES bank_user(userid)
);
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34665947)